# MVC Pagination in .Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I need to implement pagination. In controller, I ma just returning json data. View is purely client side development, MVC helpers are not implemented. View is done fully with jquery. Parameters are passed to controller through Ajax call and I am returning json data based on parameters by filtering data. How to implement pagination in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. You'll need to do your own research, first, and try something. Then, if you run into issues, you can come back and ask *specific* questions about that.

Comment: You'll have to write the client side code that interprets the JSON data that you return back from the server and then displays it as pagination links on the page.  What is it exactly that you're struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

As example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

you have specific problems?

Comment: Yeah, I saw this link. I was just thinking maybe I should implement in different way as my view is completely built in client side language. I am not using any model and helpers in view.

Comment: I'd suggest giving it a try and then seeing what problems you face.

Comment: You will need to split data on the server-side, but instead of view to return JSON. On client-side you can use library from https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/pagination/ or other

Comment: Thanks. I will try